# Erro fetch_array() no php7

Tags: php

Usava esse código na versão 5 do php, mas depois que mudei para o php 7, apareceu esse erro.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array()
>   on array

```
$selec = $mysqli->query("SELECT cpf_cnpj, isento, ... ");
$exec = $selec->fetch_assoc();

while($campos = $exec->fetch_array()) {
    extract($campos);
    $Array = Array(); 

    $Array[] = Array(
                        "cpf_cnpj"  => "$cpf_cnpj",
                        "isento"    => "$isento", 
                    ); 

    $json_encode = json_encode($Array); 
    echo $json_encode; 
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Obrigado.

Comment: muito provavle algum  erro na sua query coloque esse codigo apos a query e veja se té algum  erro  or $mysqli->query("SELECT cpf_cnpj, isento, ... ") die(mysqli_error($db))

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons apareceu esse erro **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'die' (T_EXIT)**

Comment: faltou um "or" ai antes do die    
$mysqli->query("SELECT cpf_cnpj, isento, ... ")  or die(mysqli_error($db))

Comment: @MarcosBrinnerpikatoons Não é erro na Query, voltou com o mesmo erro **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on array**

Answer (score 0):

Mude o seu codigo você está fazendo o  fetch() das vezes  coloque o  MYSQLI_ASSOC dentro do seu  Fetch_array()

```
<?php
$selec = $mysqli->query("SELECT cpf_cnpj, isento, ... ");


while($campos = $selec->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {



    $json_encode = json_encode($campos); 
    echo $json_encode; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Não aparece erro, mas também não aparece resultado, fica tela em branco.

Comment: fiz uma alteração no  codigo dentro do while tente agora